# I get different output when printing a matrix of char

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, char, variable-assignment

I'm trying to program the game Minefield. I think the best way to make the field is to use a matrix  of char. I ask the user for the difficulty, fill the matrix and then output the result just to see if that worked, but it doesn't, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int selectDifficulty(){
    int d;
    do{
        printf("--------Selezionare difficolta' del campo minato--------\n");
        printf("1: Principiante (9x9)\n");
        printf("2: Intermedio (16x16)\n");
        printf("3: Esperto (30x16)\n");
        printf(">>>: ");
        scanf("%d", &d);
    }while(d<1 || d>3);
    return d;
}

int main(){
    int d,numCols,numRows;
    
    d = selectDifficulty();

    //Create numRows x numRows matrix based on difficulty d
    if(d==1){
        numCols=9;
        numRows=9;
    }
    else if (d==2){
        numCols=16;
        numRows=16;
    }
    else{
        numCols=30;
        numRows=16;   
    }
    
    char field[numRows][numCols];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){      
        for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
            field[i][j] = "a";
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){      
        for(int j = 0; j < numRows; j++){
            printf("%c",field[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output i get:

```
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
ÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕÕ
```

What am i doing wrong?

I tried using malloc to make the matrix but i get the same output.

Comment: `field[i][j] = "a";` Change `"a"` to `'a'`... It's a char, not a string.

Comment: damn... this is Python's fault, i got too used to it ahaha. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, as it was already pointed out you are using a string literal to initialize objects of the type `char`.

```
field[i][j] = "a";
```

In this case the string literal `"a"` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *` and in fact you have

```
field[i][j] = &"a"[0];
```

Instead of the string literal you have to use integer character constant `'a'`

```
field[i][j] = 'a';
```

Also instead of the nested for loops

```
for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){      
    for(int j = 0; j < numCols; j++){
        field[i][j] = 'a';
    }
}
```

you could use standard C function `memset` declared in header `<string.h>`. For example

```
memset( field, 'a', sizeof( field ) );
```

Also you have a typo in the nested for loop that output the array

```
for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){      
    for(int j = 0; j < numRows; j++){
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
        printf("%c",field[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Instead of `numRows` you have to use `numCols` in the inner for loop.

And to output the two-dimensional array you cold use only one for loop as for example

```
for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){ 
    printf( "%.*s\n", numCols, field[i] );       
}
```

Also these if statements

```
if(d==1){
    numCols=9;
    numRows=9;
}
else if (d==2){
    numCols=16;
    numRows=16;
}
else{
    numCols=30;
    numRows=16;   
}
```

would be more readable if to introduce an enumration.

```
enum { Principiante = 1, Intermedio = 2, Esperto = 3 };

switch ( d )
{
default:
case Principiante:
    numCols=9;
    numRows=9;
    break;

case Intermedio:
    numCols=16;
    numRows=16;
    break;

case Esperto:
    numCols=30;
    numRows=16;   
    break;
}

char field[numRows][numCols];

memset( field, 'a', sizeof( field ) );

for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++){ 
    printf( "%.*s\n", numCols, field[i] );       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
field[i][j] = "a";
```

is assigning a pointer converted from the *string literal* (an array) `"a"` to `field[i][j]`.

To store a character, you should do:

```
field[i][j] = 'a';
```

If you want to stick to use a string literal for some reason, you can do:

```
field[i][j] = "a"[0];
```

or:

```
field[i][j] = *"a";
```

Do turn on compiler warnings to catch simple errors like this.

Comment: thanks so much. I use vscode, how can i turn on the warnings?

Answer (score 1):

The key mistake is not enabling all warnings with a good compiler.

```
field[i][j] = "a";  // bad
```

... is readily warned as a problem.

```
warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

Fix with enabling many warnings.. Example: `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` with gcc and:

```
field[i][j] = 'a';
```